# products like this

Tags: expresso-store

Does Exp:resso Store offer "Related Products"? An example would be on the page for a Micheal Jackson CD. Is there a built in logic that displays recommendations "You might like Janet Jackson". If so, can you send me a link with more information on this functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Store products are just regular channel entries so you can use any of the regular relationship methods used in EE to relate them. Although there is no ready-made way of adding a "you may also like..." feature it's fairly easy to add with EE right out of the box.

In addition to using categories to relate products that Iain mentioned, EllisLab have completely revamped this area in EE 2.6+. You can read about it [on their blog](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/relationships-evolved-for-expressionengine-2.6) or [in the documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html). Both provide some useful examples.

If you're using an older version of EE than [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) has been a loyal companion for many years and filled the gap prior to EE 2.6. You may still prefer to use that over EE's default relationship handling.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Expresso store but natively in EE if you are using categories for your products, you could take a look at the [related_categories_mode parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode) on the channel:entries tag.

That will show entries filed under the same category as the current single entry being viewed.

Another alternative would be to use tagging for your products, using something like [Solspace Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/). That has a [related_entries tag](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/related_entries/) which will display entries tagged similarly to the currently viewed entry.

Hope that helps.